# Shell script not running as by "./" but it runs by "sh"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-permissions, bash-scripting

I am running a script on arm target board as a super user, i.e., as a root user. But the script is not executing if i run it with following syntax

```
root@freescale$ ./Script.sh 
-sh: ./Script.sh: Permission denied
```

I already gave the read and execute permissions(+rx) by using chmod command. On executing "ls -l" command I get following attributes

```
root@freescale$ ls -l | grep Script.sh
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          362 Jul  2 08:47 Script.sh
```

"x" is not there in the file attributes column, whereas the chmod command executed successfully.
On the other hand, this script runs when I run it as

```
root@freescale$ sh Script.sh
```

Can anyone help me to answer this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if your "chmod" returns success, the execute bit does not really get turned on, as "ls" shows, therefore I conclude something is transparently preventing you from changing the file mode on the filesystem.

what does "lsattr Script.sh" shows?

can you put the script into a ramdrive or another filesystem on the same host and try again?

Comment: It gives following error :
`lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on Script.sh`

Comment: what filesystem is Script.sh stored on? see the second question I've asked, too

Comment: Well, I have placed it on a flash drive (type vfat) and mounted on /mnt partition. And the rootfs I am using is UBIFS. I am running it directly from the flash drive.On other system it runs fine without any issue

Comment: This subject has been discussed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23108/trying-to-make-file-executable-on-usb-but-the-permission-doesnt-stick) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22778/how-can-i-run-an-executable-from-a-cd-when-it-doesnt-have-the-executable-bit-se). It seems impossible to execute script from such a device. Perhaps take a look at the post mentioning `mount` with `exec` in the second thread.

Comment: what is the output of "mount" command?

Comment: I was able to directly run a .sh script by mounting with umask=000 (as described in the second thread posted by @ssssteffff) - ie "mount -o umask=000 -t vfat [...]"  

Can you do the same and re-run ls?

Comment: @Costin Gușă: O/P of mount command
`rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
ubi0:gpmi-nfc-general-use on / type ubifs (rw,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
...
/dev/mtdblock4 on /mnt/mtdblock4 type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/usb/sda1 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fmask=0111,dmask=0000,allow_utime=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,quiet,flush,errors=remount-ro)
`

Comment: are you able mount it as described above?

Comment: @Costin Gușă : I think I got the answer from some other post, its bcz noexec flag for the flash filesystem is set, thats why I am not able to set execution bit for the Script.sh, but I dont know why I am able to run it by `sh Script.sh`

Comment: @are you able mount it as described above? – Costin Gușă : Yes, it was self detected and mounted in a location /mnt/usb/sda1/<flashdrive content>

Comment: you can run it with sh because sh is in fact something like /bin/sh and Script.sh is the argument to /bin/sh which is already executable. so either run via sh or mount with exec (which is among default options) and umask=000 or whatever mask you need as long as it preserves the executable flag

Comment: yes, i haven't thougt of it! Anyways Thanks! to both Costin Gușă and  ssssteffff

Comment: Another work-around would be to add `alias Script="sh Script.sh"` to your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2):

Your script does not have the "execute" rights set for anybody. Try:

```
chmod u+x Script.sh
```

and the owner of the file should be able to start it with ./Script.sh

Similarly,

```
chmod g+x Script.sh
chmod o+x Script.sh
```

work if you want the group (g) or anybody (o) to be allowed to execute it.

Comment: I tried it but its still the same, no change

Comment: `chmod 755 ./Script.sh` did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

The file has to be "executable" in order to be executed using `./Script.sh`.

Use `chmod +x Script.sh` to add the "execute" flag for this file.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I missed an important detail in your post, you already did that, but did not work... try executing `chmod` again, then immediately execute `echo $?` to get the exit status, it may be help.

Comment: I got success status (i.e 0) on performing `echo $?`